# Adding object to array of arrays

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add an object to an array of arrays, but when i do, i am recieving an error in my array of array unit tests, stating :- "undefined method 'has_key' for nil:NilClass". However, if i try and add a string or number to the array of array, it works absolutely fine.

I set up my array of arrays like this

```
@array_of_array= Array.new(5) { Array.new(3) }
```

Now if I try to do this

```
@array_of_array[0][0] = MyObject.new
```

Then if I run my unit tests against @array_of_array, i get the error.

But if I try to do this

```
@array_of_array[0][0] = 'Test'
```

Theres no problem.

--Edited---

Heres failing test

```
it "should place object in correct starting position" do
array_of_array= Array.new(5) { Array.new(3) }
array_of_array[1][0] = MyObject.new
array_of_array.should eql('fail on purpose..want to see output')
```

end

Im new to ruby, so unsure of where im going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the code of the failing test?

Comment: Works for me. `has_key` is a method called on a Hash, not an Array, so can you paste the stack trace?

Comment: does `a = MyObject.new` work?

Comment: no a = myObject.new fails as well

Comment: @namtax: That would indicate that the problem lies with `MyObject.new` rather than with the array.

Comment: Ok, if i remove the initialize method from the object it works, not sure why my initialize method isnt functioning properly

Answer (score 1):

Like Claw said, the error probably means that your `MyObject.new` statement is returning a nil object for some reason. Then you're trying to call the function 'has_key' of that nil object.

Does your MyObject class throw an exception if you use `.new!` instead of `.new` ? If so, you could see why it's failing to return a proper MyObject object.

**Edit**

To catch an exception inside your 'new' method for the MyObject model, you could do something like:

```
def new
    begin
        #whatever is done in this method
    rescue => exception
        puts exception.message
    end
end
```

Comment: Ok, when i try MyObject.new! I get :- NoMethodError: undefined method 'new!' for MyObject

Comment: Yeah. So there is no exception throwing .new method for your MyObject class. You could put a begin rescue statement inside the 'new' function in the model and see if it throws an exception (Look at edit in answer).

Comment: Hi Vota I actually abandoned my approach of storing the object in the array, so didnt get opportunity to try your solution. Its true that the error was occurring because the new statement was returning a nil object.

Comment: @namtax No worries. Glad I could be of some help :)